# distance metric between multisets

Tags: metric-spaces, multisets

I am trying to define a distance $F(X,Y)$ between two multisets $X$ and $Y$. For each pair of $x \in X , y \in Y$ there exists a distance function $f(x,y)$ which takes the range of $[0,1]$. An additional requirement of $F(X,Y)$ is that $F=0$ if one of $X,Y$ is a multiple of the other. Does anyone know if there is some established metric that satisfies these requirements, or maybe provide me with some literature source to begin with?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to nonstandardly use $\in^\#$ to refer to the version of $\in$ that returns a natural number indicating the multiplicity of an element in a multiset. I will assume that values cannot occur a negative number of times or an infinite number of times.

I am assuming that "is a multiple of" means that there exists some fixed constant $c$ so that, for all $a$, $(a \in^\# X) = c \times (a \in^\# Y)$.

One thing you can do, assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are both finite, is to "flatten" them into probability distributions. A finite multiset can be viewed as a discrete distribution over its elements.

Now that you have two probability distributions, one choice of metric is the [earth mover distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance). Another choice of metric is the [Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_statistic). A third choice is the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), but that has the disadvantage of not being symmetric and thus isn't a true metric.